# Mook Stress Boxes in Fate Core

Tags: fate-core, stress

When I was looking at the section in the Fate Core rules on designing a "Good" mook on page 215, I saw the following:

> Stress: Two stress boxes—a three shift hit is enough to take them out.

I feel like this is wrong. If it has 2 stress boxes, then a 3-shift hit would take out the 1-shift box and the 2-shift box, but that still wouldn't be enough to take it out.

It seems to do it right on the other examples:

Average:

> No stress boxes—a one shift hit is enough to take them out.

Fair:

> Stress: One stress box—a two shift hit is enough to take them out.

Am I reading this wrong? Do Mooks' stress boxes only suck up 1 shift at a time, regardless of quantity of boxes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you're reading it wrong. Each stress box can absorb a number of shifts of its ordinal or less, and you can only use one at a time. Not just mooks. From p.160:

> When you take stress, check off a stress box with a value equal to the shift value of the hit. If that box is already checked, check off a higher value box. If there is no higher available box, and you can't take any consequences, you're taken out of the conflict. **You can only check off one stress box per hit.**

(emphasis mine)

So, when a hit lands for 3 stress on any character with 2 stress boxes, there is no box available to absorb the hit. Without consequences, a mook must be taken out. A character with consequences available could choose to take one or more, but still only **one stress box** can be checked per hit.

Comment: Wow, that totally changes the way I play the game. So while it could survive a one-shift hit and a two-shift hit, it can't survive a three-shift hit? Interesting...

Comment: Note that a character *can* take multiple _consequences_ from a given hit, assuming they have them available to take. So if you have only two stress boxes and take a hit for 7, you could take a moderate consequence, a mild consequence, and mark off your 1-stress box.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus - You are correct and I have edited the answer to make that clear.